# how can i install apt-get on Centos

Tags: centos, apt

```
I am getting:
yum install apt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * base: mirror.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * updates: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
Setting up Install Process
No package apt available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Any new Red Hat admins hired into your environment are going to hate you.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Hatters gonna hate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-rpm is in [Repoforge](http://repoforge.org/).

Comment: can you write commands to install it from Repoforge

Answer (score 0):

First what would you install apt instead of having yum? And second you'll need to find a source to had to yum so it can install apt, but because the two programs (apt and yum) are doing the same job but on different platform I don't think you will find one.

So I think you'll need to build apt from source (see on [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net)).